# How to sort null as the first item?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a Person Class and it has an list of Jobs

```
 public class Person
 {
      public List<Job> Jobs;
 }

 public class Job
 {
     public string Name;
     public DateTime StartDate;
     public DateTime? EndDate;
 }
```

I want to create a method on the Person class called **CurrentOrLastJob()**  which would

1. return a job without an enddate
2. If all jobs have an end date would then return the most recent enddate.

What is the right "OrderByDescending() method on a DateTime? type so that the null item shows up first (as by default it seems to show up last)

```
public Job CurrentOrLastJob()
{
     var lastJob = Jobs.OrderByDescending(r=>r.EndDate).FirstorDefault();
     return lastJob; 
}
```

Comment: With this impressive amount of badges, I'm suprised to see that you didn't work too much on the title of this question. Could you remove the tag from it (C#) and reword it so it touches the topic (sorting `null` as the-first-item)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the null coalescing operator to supply a default value for the date that gives you the value you want.

```
Jobs.OrderByDescending(r => r.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue)
```

This treats any null value as the maximum date/time value, so when sorted descending it will appear first.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two steps - first by whether or not `EndDate` has a value (putting jobs with no end date first), then the `EndDate` value itself.

```
Jobs.OrderBy(j => j.EndDate.HasValue ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenByDescending(j => j.EndDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

That way you don't have to worry about where `null`, `true`, and `false` values fall when ordering.

Comment: The problem is 6 months form now when someone looks at it and has to decipher what it's _supposed_ to do.  I prefer clear, concise code to minification or micro-performance tuning.

Comment: I totally agree and that's why I suggested that. Two-phase sorting over abstract/artificial criteria is actually more complicated than simple substitution/coalescing. But, oh well, someone already added that snippet as another answer. I'll clear the comments later.